# Multiple classes inheritance for LitElement

Tags: javascript, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, extends, es6-class

I'm trying already for a while to implement a utility (or to find a good package) to extend a `LitElement` with multiple classes that add functionalities to it (Loading variables, Conditional rendering for example), but I want to avoid to create a mixin for every of these classes and execute them when extending.

What I want to achieve is something like this, and all the code is executed on the latest browsers without any transpile process:

```
class NewElement extends combineClasses(LitElement, AFunctionalities, BFunctionalities) {
  constructor() {}
  methods...
}
```

Right now I'm trying a solution found here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189466/JavaScript-ES-Multiple-Inheritance-Class but seems not to work:

```
properties-changed.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
  at new PropertiesChanged (properties-changed.js:170)
  at new PropertiesMixin (properties-mixin.js:111)
  at new LitElement (lit-element.ts:102)
  at new classes (elements.js:63)
  at new NewElement (leaderboards.js:76)
  at render (shady-render.ts:160)
  at HTMLElement._applyRender (lit-element.ts:286)
  at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (lit-element.ts:218)
  at HTMLElement._flushProperties (properties-changed.js:387)
  at HTMLElement._flushProperties (lit-element.ts:232)
```

Every help will help me to reach my final goal. Thank you :)

Comment: "*I want to avoid to create a mixin for every of these classes and execute them when extending.*" - why?

Comment: 1) I can instantiate independently them
2) I simpler syntax

Comment: #1 - do you mean that each of them is a plain `class` that could be used like `new AFunctionalities()`?

Comment: Yes. Every of them is a plain class, you took the class, take its properties (constructor, methods) and attach them (properly, in the scope chain) to a finalClass result that will be extended by the current declared class.

Comment: If they are individual classes, each with its own inheritance hierarchy, what do you mean by "*properly, in the scope chain*"? Multiple inheritance is impossible in JS.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi . I know it's impossible. By properly i mean every new created Class to have the prototype of that one that it's extending. Anyway... i lost a lot of time, i switched now to classic mixins.